# Visualize visual words in bag of words model

Tags: computer-vision, sift

I am implementing visual bag of words through these steps:

1. Find interest points using SIFT
2. Calculate SIFT descriptor
3. Build codebook through kmeans clustering of SIFT descriptors.

How can I visualize these visual words? For example in the following lecture, how do they get those patches?

[image]

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue. Did you manage to plot the visual words on diagram? I'm trying to reproduce the following picture:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUXoH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUXoH.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Each SIFT descriptor corresponds to a region of the image. You take these from a bunch of images and group them into some number of clusters. I think what he's showing in the slide there is just a few samples from each cluster where he chose human-meaningful names for the clusters after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone might be interested in my question, this is how the patches are created:

1) For each codebook, find the closest interest point that has SIFT descriptor closest to the codebook

2) Simply print out a window around that interest point.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to your self-answer, the codebook is only one for the whole training set, it describes a set of visual words which might have some Human interpretation but it is not guaranteed.

Regarding on how to extract the patches of each keypoint I would say you have to consider as well the scale at which it was extracted (if a scale invariant descriptor was used) or the relevant path size of the descriptor itself.

As side comment, don't use the visualization of keypoints assigned to visual words as a measure of quality of your BoF model, several factors influence it and what the computer grants as similar might not have human interpretation as said before.